# Docker: Nodemon is syncing but not re-running

Tags: docker, binding, nodemon, application-restart

I am new at `Docker`.

The files are syncing upon changes using the `bind mount`, but the `nodemon` is not re-running. To see the changes, I have to stop the container and restart using `docker compose up`.

*I tried so many solutions but the problem still remains.*

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:18-alpine3.17
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json /app
RUN npm ci
COPY . /app
EXPOSE 3000
# CMD [ "npm", "run", "dev" ]
```

docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: "3.9"

services:
  frontend:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: npm run dev
    container_name: study-001-frontend-reactjs
    networks:
      - study-001
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - /app/node_modules

networks:
  study-001:
```

package.json

```json
{
    "name": "001-study",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "type": "module",
    "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
        "dev": "nodemon index.js"
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
        "express": "^4.18.2"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "nodemon": "^2.0.20"
    }
}
```

[image]

git repo:

Everything is working fine if I am running the project without using Docker.

What am I missing..?

Git repository:
https://pammysayshello@bitbucket.org/pammysayshello/docker-issue.git

Comment: You don't seem to actually be using anything out of your image in this setup.  I'm not clear what makes Docker necessary here; would it be easier to run Node directly on your host system?

Comment: Actually, this is just a sample code that I created for resolving this issue that I am facing. The project is much bigger than this which I need to shift on `Docker`.

Comment: You can still use Docker to integration-test and deploy a larger project while using ordinary non-container development tools for day-to-day work.  If you project does work without Docker, can you use that while you're actually doing development, and then `docker build` an image for system tests?

Comment: I understand, but it has been decided by the company to move the projects to docker containers. So, I have no other choice. And besides this is also given me an opportunity to get familiar with the docker.

Comment: I have created a git repository with this code and added the link.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the nodemon is not being installed correctly in the docker container.

*Try this*

:

docker-compose.yml:
remove the volume /app/nodemodules.

```
volumes:
  - .:/app
```

Dockerfile:

try using npm i instead of npm ci.

```
RUN npm install
```

Change copy package*.json ./app to package*.json ./

```
COPY package*.json ./
```

Already you have declared a workdir as /app so replace copy . /app with copy . .

```
COPY . .
```

Finally kill the container, delete the image and execute docker-compose up again

Comment: No, still not working

Comment: What about adding restart:always in the service. This keeps the container running and restablishes connection incase the service is down for whatever reason

Comment: That didn't work either.